# can't make select+update transaction in mariadb execute atomically

Tags: mysql, python-3.4, mariadb, peewee

I'm attempting to parallelize a python script by using a "tasks" table in mariadb where each row describes a task and each running instance of my script does something like this simplified python + peewee code:

```
with db.transaction() as txn: 
   result = list(Table.raw("select id from tasks where started=0 limit 1"))
   if len(result) == 0:
      sys.exit("nothing left to do")

   my_next_task = result[0]

   # mark this task as started
   Table.raw("update tasks set started=1 where id=%s" % my_next_task.id)

# process my_next_task
```

However, when I start 2 instances of my script simultaneously, they both start working on the same task. Am I misunderstanding how transactions are supposed to work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The following code is guaranteed to have only 1 thread acquire the lock before executing the task

1.The fact that you are doing a transaction, makes sure only 1 thread can do an update at a time

2.Note that, we need to check for started = 0. This makes sure only 1 thread can do the update

```
with db.transaction() as txn: 
   result = list(Table.raw("select id from tasks where started=0 limit 1"))

   // The update query should return number of rows updated. So if a thread updates the task, it should return 1, which means it acquired a lock. If not, it means the thread didn't acquire the lock
   got_lock = Table.raw("update tasks set started=1 where id=%s and started = 0" % my_next_task.id) > 0 

   if len(result) == 0:
      sys.exit("nothing left to do")

   my_next_task = if(got_lock) result[0] else return
```

Comment: Thanks! that should work (though I think you meant started=0 instead of started <> 0)

Comment: I must be misunderstanding transactions then. Doesn't grouping several queries in a transaction guarantee that together they will execute as 1 atomic operation (or be rolled back otherwise)?

Comment: Yea, I meant started = 0

Comment: Transaction doesn't guarantee the read locks, which means 2 reads can happen in parallel. In your code you were processing the task right after the reads. So the same task gets executed twice. Also the updates are idempotent in your case, which means they can be executed one after the other. So there is nothing to rollback, as there can be no conflict updating started = 1 on the same row twice.

Comment: In my code tasks are only processed after the read+write transaction  (at # process my_next_task). I understand reads can happen in parallel, but the read+write together are not idempotent. I thought wrapping the read+write in a transaction would ensure that this executed as if each "read+write" transaction occurred serially in some order.

Comment: is this not the case?